# VB .NET MVC LinqToSql exception with Update/Insert methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq-to-sql

First time posting. I have been going round and around with this one and no one seems to have the same problem I do.

When I try to either update/or insert an object using Linq to SQL, these methods work fine but then I get the following exception when it hits the Save() method

```
    System.ArgumentNullException was caught
    Message="Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source"
    ParamName="source"
    Source="System.Data.Linq"
    StackTrace:
     at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SendOnValidate(MetaType type, TrackedObject item, ChangeAction changeAction)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.ValidateAll(IEnumerable`1 list)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
   at ilaTraining.TrainingRepository.Save() in C:\Users\kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ilaTraining\ilaTraining\Models\TrainingRepository.vb:line 394
   at ilaTraining.AdminController.CreateCourseTitle(t_courseTitle title) in C:\Users\kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ilaTraining\ilaTraining\Controllers\AdminController.vb:line 433
```

The object I am passing into the insertOnSubmit or updateOnSubmit methods is fully formed and doesn't break referential integrity as far as I can tell. All the values which are non nulls are filled etc.

I thought it might have been the connection string or something like that but if I manually put information into the database the application can retrieve that. Just not change it.

This is driving me nuts, so if any kind soul out their wishes to put me out of my misery then please do so. Thanks for any/all help and apologies to any moderators I may have upset by posting this in the wrong place.

Thanks

Comment: what's the value of `source`? Isn't it null? Does your DB accept null for that value?